# Component is rendering without even use of useEffect and useState

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, use-effect, use-state

**What happening is that I am not using useEffect & useState still it rendering the updated state when I remove item from cart, Is this because of Redux??**

**I am beginner in react and so far what I learned is when any change happen we use useEffect or useState to update the state. But here i am confused.**

```
const CartScreen = ({ history, match, location }) => {
  const qty = location.search ? Number(location.search.split('=')[1]) : 1
  console.log(qty)

  const cart = useSelector((state) => state.cart)

  const { cartItems } = cart
  console.log(cart)
  console.log("Render again")

  const dispatch = useDispatch()
```

**This is my removeItem handler**

```
 const removeItemHandler = (id) => {
    dispatch(cartRemoveItem(id))
  }
```

```
  
  return (
    <div className="CartScreen">
      <div className="CartItem_Container">
        {cartItems.length === 0 ? (
          <p>No item</p>
        ) : (
          cartItems.map((product) => {
            return (
              <>
                <div className="Cart_Card">
                  <div>
                    <img src={product.image} width="70px" height="70px"></img>
                  </div>
                  <div className="Cart_Breif">
                    <p className="CartProduct_Name">
                      {product.name}{' '}
                      <span className="qty">
                        <select
                          value={product.qty}
                          onChange={(e) => {
                            dispatch(
                              cartAddItem(
                                product.product,
                                Number(e.target.value)
                              )
                            )
                          }}
                        >
                          {[...Array(product.countInStock).keys()].map((x) => (
                            <option key={x + 1} value={x + 1}>
                              {x + 1}
                            </option>
                          ))}
                        </select>
                      </span>
                    </p>
                    <p className="About_Product">{product.description} </p>

                    <p className="price">
                      ${product.price}{' '}
                      <span className="removeItem" onClick={()=> removeItemHandler(product.product)}>Remove</span>
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </>
            )
          })
        )}
      </div>

      <div className="ProceedTo_Checkout"
        onClick={() => {
          history.push('/address')
        }}
      >
        <p>Proceed To CheckOut</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default CartScreen
```

Comment: Your cart state is changed in redux and useSelector update the cart state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your component re-renders because of `useSelector`. You are most probably updating the store by dispatching `cartRemoveItem`. [useSelector](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#useselector) hook compares the latest selector value in redux store with the previous selector value and forces component to be re-rendered if they are different.

Answer (score 1):

the component rerender whenever a states or props are changed , if you use the useSelector hook then on a particular state then your component will track any change of that state and rerender whenever it changed